# How to draw an arc using highcharts renderer with rounded edges?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, highcharts

I'm trying to draw an arc with the highcharts renderer and give it rounded edges. I tried setting the `stroke-linecap` and `stroke-linejoin` to be 'round'. That does not seem to do the trick though. Any tips?

[Jsfiddle to test your ideas on](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/renderer-arc/)

Comment: If you can access external libraries, I recommend the `arc(x,y,width,height,start,stop)` is the processing.js library.

Comment: The problem is that `stroke-_name` applies.. to stroke. Not to the shape itself. In that case, you can set width of the shape to be 0px, but set higher stroke-width, please take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/6wbtzxae/1/